# how to persist object and variables in service after killing the app

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have  created on service in `START_STICKY`mode

following is my service class

```
public class KeepAliveStatusMessageService extends Service {
private Timer keepAliveStatusMessageTimer;
private TimerTask timerJob;
private JsHandler javaSHandler;

protected void doInBackground() {
    javaSHandler =LoginActivity.javaSHandler; //JSHandlerSingleton.getInstance().getJavaSHandlerLogin();
    keepAliveStatusMessageTimer = new Timer();
    AllTimer.getInstance().setKeepAliveStatusMessageTimer(keepAliveStatusMessageTimer);
    timerJob = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UserInformationProvider userInformationProvider = UserInformationProvider.getInstance();
            javaSHandler =GladiusLoginActivity.javaSHandler;
            Log.v("Service","called");
            javaSHandler.keepAliveStatusMessage(userInformationProvider.getIpAddress(), userInformationProvider.getUsername(), userInformationProvider.getSessionId());
        }

        ;
    };
    keepAliveStatusMessageTimer.schedule(timerJob, 5 * 1000, 5 * 1000);
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    doInBackground();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

This service work perfectly when I use my app or goes in background, 
but when I kill my app by swiping  from background I am getting following error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
>                                                                             Process: com.me.cst, PID: 18897
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.me.interfaces.JsHandler.keepAliveStatusMessage(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at com.me.service.KeepAliveStatusMessageService$1.run(KeepAliveStatusMessageService.java:67)
>                                                                                 at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

I don't know why JsHandler becoming null after killing the app.
Please Help me to call that method after killing the app as service is not getting aborted only that value is becoming null. 
Any suggesting is appreciated..
Pardon my English...

**EDIT1:** JsHandler is abject of JsHandler.java class. this class is used to call the java script method from there network call will be sent.
following is a briefing of JsHandler class 
**JsHandler.java**

```
    public class JsHandler {
    Activity activity;
    WebView webView;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
   public JsHandler(Activity _contxt, WebView _webView, Handler handler) {
        activity = _contxt;
        webView = _webView;
        this.handler = handler;
    }
public void keepAliveStatusMessage(String ip, String username, String sessionId) {
        final String webUrl = "javascript:keepAliveStatusMessage('" + ip + "','" + username + "','" + sessionId + "')";
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl(webUrl);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have created a static variable of JsHandler  in LoginActivity.java 
I made it static variable because I am not able to pass object through putExtra method

```
public  static JsHandler javaSHandler;
```

and assigned value in on start method

```
javaSHandler = new JsHandler(this, loginWebView, new Handler());
```

In KeepAliveStatusMessage.java class, I am accessing that static variable.
to call the keepAlive method of JsHandler class.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why JsHandler becoming null after killing the app.

Your process was terminated. Then, Android started up a fresh process for you, to start a fresh copy of your sticky service. However, you are referring to a `static` field (`GladiusLoginActivity.javaSHandler`), which will not be initialized in this new process. Hence, you crash when trying to call methods on that object, since it will be `null`.

Comment: So is there a way to solve this issue
I tried Singleton class but that giving me null

Comment: @MKY: I have no idea what `javaSHandler` is, what it does, why it is a singleton, and why you think it would exist. I do not even know what this entire service is for, as it does not seem to do anything. So, perhaps the solution is to get rid of the service itself. Beyond that, I cannot really help you, unless you edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what you are trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: @MKY: Definitely get rid of the service. When your process terminates, **your `WebView` is gone**, and so there is nothing for the service to do.

Comment: suppose I will remove Webview form there...
then that variable can persist after killing the app?